Surreal British 80s-90s movie where a woman dreams of children dancing around a giant orange egg/sphere
This is a long shot, but I'll take it anyway.
As a child, I remember seeing this surreal movie on TV that eluded my understanding completely. My grasp of English at the time and the movie medium wasn't as good as it is today, and I've always been curious about it.
Here's what I remember:

I saw it sometime in the late 80s to early 90s, but the movie itself may very well be older.
I recall it was British.
It followed a woman walking around and living in a town that seemed poor.
I had a feeling that the movie was set around a time of war (probably WWII) or directly after. The imagery of the struggling town to me evoked the Great Depression era.
The woman would often have dreams or hallucinations about children dancing around a large egg or sphere-shaped object. I recall it was orange in color.
At the very end, she seems to have found this egg or sphere, and another smiling woman opens it up for her and they both go inside.

Does it ring any bells?

There is a giant breast rolling about a town in Every Thing You Always Wanted to Know About Sex * But Were Afraid that might fit the bill.  I don't recall the specific details though.

I just read the description on IMDB. I'm afraid that's not it at all. But thanks :)

The only movie I know with a "giant orange sphere" is James and the Giant Peach (1996). It fits some of the criteria but the main crux of the story is about a young boy travelling to New York in the peach to escape his horrid aunts.

Definitely not that one. It's live action for one.

@SystemDown James and the Giant Peach is live action.

@Craig - I guess I meant acted out fully by live actors as opposed to puppets and the like :)

@SystemDown lol there are live actors in the movie :-P Have you ever seen it?

@Craig - "Acted out fully by live actors". The movie I saw had no puppets or animation.

@SystemDown lol ok ^_^
